# get String Array from onpostExecute

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask

I first want to pass the array res to another class. for this I created a get method. Unfortunately the array outside of onPostExecute is empty and I get an error. The call of the data is also delayed, because I thought that it has not yet loaded the data, but there also comes the error. I also checked the class to see if the array is full and it is. How do I get the data from the onPostExecute?
I have already looked at other problems, but do not quite understand the solution to them. Maybe someone here can help me.

```
public class FetchDataRoulette extends AsyncTask<Object,String,String> {
    String googleNearByPlacesData;
    String url;
    String[] res;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

            res=new String[jsonArray.length()];


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject getLocation=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

                String lat=getLocation.getString("lat");
                String lng=getLocation.getString("lng");

                JSONObject getName=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String name=getName.getString("name");

                LatLng latLng=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng));

                res[i]=name;
            }

            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String[] getRes(){
        Log.d("Test",res[1]);
        return res;
    }
    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {

        try{
            url=(String) objects[0];
            DownloadUrl downloadUrl=new DownloadUrl();
            googleNearByPlacesData= downloadUrl.retireveUrl(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googleNearByPlacesData;
    }
}
```

I have read the array and checked it.  Also in different places. I have made a delayed query so that the values are written.